# Не могу скачать фото по url

Tags: python, веб-программирование, urllib

Вот несколько кодов в которых я пытался скачать:

```
import urllib

resource = urllib.urlopen(img)
out = open("http://thiscatdoesnotexist.com/?1582681489783=1/cat.jpg", 'wb')
out.write(resource.read())
out.close()
```

Ошибка:
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen'

Второй код:

```
import urllib.request
url = "http://thiscatdoesnotexist.com/?1582681489783=1/cat.jpeg"
img = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
out = open("/storage/emulated/0/LeraBotVK/cat.jpeg", "wb")
out.write(img)
out.close
```

Ошибка: raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Answer (score 1):

Если не принципиально использовать `urllib`:

```
import requests
url = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/4euWl.jpg?s=64&g=1"
res = requests.get(url).content
with open(url.split('/')[-1].split('?')[0], 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res)
```

Comment: Изображение скачалось, но он типо сломанное, оно появилось, но при открытии, фото повреждённое(

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте с этим кодом.

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve(img, "...\img.jpg")
```

Либо этим

```
import urllib

resource = urllib.urlopen(img)
out = open("...\img.jpg", 'wb')
out.write(resource.read())
out.close()
```