# Как сохранить svg картинку с сайта?

Tags: python

Как сохранить svg картинку с сайта? Python
Желательно без использование selenium

Comment: А можно URL картинки, хотя-бы.

Comment: одно из двух: либо [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1089233/178576), либо [mcve]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу скачать фото по url](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1089233/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be-url)

Comment: Максимум какую ссылку можно вытащить https://lolz.guru/threads/2541863/contest/captcha

Answer (score 0):

Для начала установите библиотеку `requests`:
`pip install requests`
Далее сможете скачать картинку с помощью такого кода:

````
import requests
url = "https://porno.hub/"
res = requests.get(url).content
with open(url.split('/')[-1].split('?')[0], 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res)```
````

Comment: так мы получим html страницу, а мне нужна jpg, png, или gif картинка самой  капчи:(
а там svg она, вот я и не знаю что делать

Comment: Попробуй с помощью urllib: ```import urllib

resource = urllib.urlopen(img)
out = open("...\img.jpg", 'wb')
out.write(resource.read())
out.close()```